# JQuery to view next class in line

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm pretty new to JQuery so I made my own light box that comes up and an exit button, it works great. I was just wondering how to make it so I can have a Next and Previous button and it will view the next image or div with the proper class assigned to it. For example, My HTML:

```
<button id="button1">Click Here</button>

<div id="view" class="outter">
    <img src="http://go.iomega.com/static/img/x_button_close.png" class="exit_button" id="close_view" />
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>stuff inside of the first div</h1>
        </div>
    <button id="previous">Prev</button><button id="next">Next</button>
</div>

<div id="view" class="outter">
    <img src="images/closebox.png" class="exit_button" id="close_view" />
        <div class="inner">
            <h1>stuff inside of the second div</h1>
        </div>
</div>
```

MY CSS

```
.outter{
    display:none; 
    width:620px; 
    height:380px; 
    top:20%; 
    left:17.5%; 
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2; 
}
.inner{
    width:600px; 
    height:330px; 
    background-color:white; 
    border:1px solid #000; 
    -moz-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111; 
    -webkit-box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111; 
    box-shadow:0px 0px 10px #111; 
    margin-top:15px;
    z-index:1; 
}
.exit_button{ 
    float:right;
    z-index:3;
}
​
```

And My JQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#button1').click(function(){ 
            $('#view').fadeIn(750);
        }); 
        $('#close_view').click(function(){ 
            $('#view').fadeOut();
        }); 
}); ​
```

Here is all of that in a JSFiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/9cU5C/29/

This all works fine but I'd like to be able to add a whole bunch of div's with the class "outter" in there and have the next button flip to the next "outter" classed div in line and vise versa with the previous button. I hope I'm explaining this properly and don't sound stupid, I'm pretty new to JQuery and I enjoy doing things like this myself to get better at it. I tryed to google the problem, and found couldn't come up with anything that I could get to work.

Thanks a bunch guys! 
-Mike

Comment: First, a quick comment.  I seem to be seeing this a lot today.  You should *never* have two things with the same ID.  If two things have something in common, they should be in the same class.  An ID uniquely identifies an element for easy retrieval and ... identification.

Comment: I began to play around with it some more and "kinda" got what I like but only when you click the next button and you can't do more then 2 divs like this http://jsfiddle.net/9cU5C/36/

Comment: @JeffB ohh, my bad. I'll change that now.

Comment: P.S. jQuery is fun.  You'll like it.

Comment: I enjoy it alot! I used to just know how to buy or download free scripts and make them work but never was able to make my own and customize it. Seeing it come to life from scratch is awesome!

Comment: I'm on a mobile, which is not conducive to coding.  If you don't have an answer tomorrow, I'll code up a simple example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make use or .next(), .prev(), and .closest().  Also, set classes on your 'next' and 'previous' buttons.

pseudo:

```
$('.next').click(function() {
   $('.outter').hide();
   $(this).closest('outter').next('outter').show();
});

$('.previous').click(function() {
   $('.outter').hide();
   $(this).closest('outter').prev('outter').show();
});
```

The concept is to hide all the elements, then make the appropriate one visible.

After you're done with your learning exercise, definitely check out the code for lightbox and see how it's done.  It's always great to try first, and then find out the 'best' approach.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for taking the time to read this. I'm working this in now. I'll let you know how it goes!

Comment: I almost got it to work, played around a little bit, very close to having this working. What I have so far http://jsfiddle.net/9cU5C/84/

Comment: @user1053263: very nice.  I led you astray with my code above.  the structure of your html was not what I expected: http://jsfiddle.net/9cU5C/108/

Comment: Trying to figure out how you did this, great work dude! Got to read into ":first" and "length ?" so I can use them in situations like this.